# Resizing pane in tmux not working with hotkeys, Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, tmux

My normal commands to move divider between panes is not working in tmux anymore. I switched from a Debian system to an Arch system. Why would Arch be different? The terminal from within tmux is "screen". I usually start tmux from a virtual console. There is no window manager running on my system right now.

For example, none of these hot keys work:

```
Ctrl-down arrow
Alt-down arrow
Shift-Ctrl-down arrow
```

I have the following bindings set in my tmux conf:

```
bind-key -n C-S-Down resize-pane -D 15
etc.
```

But as mentioned above it does not work, although it worked fine in my old system. I know the tmux conf is working properly in general because all of the other settings in conf work fine.

Note that the full command does work properly. In other words if I do this:

```
:resize-pane -D 15
```

it does work. How can I further diagnose the problem?

Comment: You didn't mention what terminal emulators tmux is talking to on each operating system.  The identities of the terminal emulators processing the keychords are quite important.

Comment: By `Ctrl-down arrow` you mean *only* this? Or tmux prefix (Ctrl-b by default) and *then* this?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Right, it is understood that all hotkeys are preceded by the tmux hotkey, which is Ctrl-A in my case.

Comment: `it is understood ...` -- Not really. Run `tmux bind-key -T root c new-window` and hit c. Your example `bind-key` command suggest you're not using `-T root` but it's not clear since you don't mention the prefix at all.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Well, it is understood, because as I said in my post, all my other tmux settings work properly, which obviously would not be the case if there was a problem with the prefix setting.

Comment: I'm not claiming there's a problem with prefix. I just want the question to be clear what sequence of keys you want to bind. It's not clear the sequence should start with prefix and what the prefix is. It may or may not be relevant, but in case it is, the information should be in the question body.

Comment: @JdeBP When I try echo $TERM from within a tmux session it responds "screen"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a problem with the terminal outside tmux. You don't mention what it is but most likely either it doesn't support these keys, or your TERM outside tmux does not match the terminal, or does not include these keys. So:

1) Make sure your terminal outside tmux sends something unique for these keys. You can check by running `cat` outside tmux then pressing for example `C-Down` and making sure you see something different from when you press `Down`. If you do not, then the terminal does not support these keys.

2) If the terminal does support the keys, then make sure `TERM` outside tmux is correct for the terminal you are running tmux in so tmux knows what to expect. For example in xterm you should be using `xterm` or `xterm-256color`, rxvt should be `rxvt` or `rxvt-256color`. Remember this is *outside* tmux - inside tmux must remain `screen` or `tmux`.

3) If the correct `TERM` outside tmux does not fix it, possibly the terminfo entry is missing the keys or is out of date. Perhaps see if you can upgrade ncurses. Or it is possible to add the keys manually with tmux's `terminal-overrides` option.